# How to efficiently use Enum objects as keys in the Map data structure?

Tags: java, dictionary, enums

Is there a more efficient and specialized implementation of a Map collection where Enum objects can serve as keys?

Comment: As well as EnumMap, there is EnumSet which can also be useful.

Comment: [Exactly right](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I learned this recently after I accidentally stumbled upon the answer in the Java API. If you ever have a map that uses enums as keys make sure you use [EnumMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html). It's very simple and *much* more efficient:

```
public interface LibraryItem{ ... }

public enum LibraryItemType{ BOOK, CD, VHS, AUDIO; ... }

Map<LibraryItemType, NavigableSet<LibraryItem>> itemsByType =
    new EnumMap<>(LibraryItemType.class);
```

Answer (score 17):

Yes. [`EnumMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is precisely that; an efficient implementation of the `Map` interface, in which the key type must be an enum:

From the [`API documentation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html):

> **`Class EnumMap<K extends Enum<K>,V>`**
>
> > *A specialized Map implementation for use with enum type keys. All of the keys in an enum map must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the map is created. Enum maps are represented internally as arrays. This representation is extremely compact and efficient.*

**Example usage:**

```
Map<MyEnum, String> map = new EnumMap<MyEnum, String>(MyEnum.class);
```

Comment: Yes... please check existing answers before replying. This was a self-answer post.

Comment: So you, 1. post an easy question of which you know the answer. 2. Write up a half-baked answer yourself immediately. 3. Down-vote other answers because you feel that it was somehow "your question to answer"? I don't get it.. why?? for reputation?

Comment: while I support your confusion, and certainly oppose the OP's downvote, I don't think there was a need for another answer about `EnumMap`. (That's why I deleted mine :) )

Comment: I wrote my answer because I didn't get why the previous answer included the LibraryItem interface and a NavigableSet of LibraryItems to illustrate the use of an EnumMap. If I knew the OP wasn't interested in an answer to the question I obviously wouldn't have bothered.  :)

Comment: 1) There's nothing wrong with self-answer posts, read the FAQ. I made this post because I knew EnumMap is not widely known and thought it would be beneficial to a lot of devs if they were aware of its existence. 2) My answer was not "half-baked" since it included an example as well as a link to the API. The only mistake I had was to use LibraryItem instead of LibraryItemType in one place which was in fact fixed by Donal, thank you Donal for catching that. So as far as I can see your answer was redundant... but that's why the community exists to settle disputes like these for us.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, it's simpler to write:

```
Map<MyEnum, String> map = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);
```

There's no need to repeat the types. This can make the code a lot easier to read.